# Jquery: Show/hide menu with single button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I am trying to make a button that calls a menu. After the menu has been called, clicking on the button should close the menu.

There are also some classes that should be added to the menu/button to assist with styling.

How can I do this? (I am using jQuery 1.8.3.)

This is my code:

```
$(function() {
    "use strict";
    $(document).on('click', '.anchor', function() {

        $('.ui-tapmenu').removeClass("animated bounceInDown");
        $('.ui-tapmenu').hide();
        $('.overlay').hide();
        var menuId = $(this).data('menu');
        var menuName = '.' + menuId;
        $(".loading").delay(1000).show(0);
        $(menuName).addClass("animated bounceInDown");
        $(menuName).show();
        $(this).addClass('close jq-close');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
        $(this).addClass('anchor');
        $(this).removeClass('close');
        $('.ui-tapmenu').removeClass("animated bounceInDown");
        $('.ui-tapmenu').hide();
        $('.overlay').hide();
        $('.anchor.jq-close').removeClass('close');
    });

});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/d4ajx/

Problem: it works, but when the menu is closed, the open code refires, so the menu stays permanently open. I am not sure why this happens, as when the "open code" runs it adds a class to the trigger. The "close code" only works on this class, so the "open code" shouldn't run again.

Here is another version:

```
$(function() {
    "use strict";
    $(document).on('click', '.anchor', function() {

        $('.ui-tapmenu').toggleClass("animated bounceInDown");
        $('.ui-tapmenu').toggle();
        $('.overlay').toggle();
        var menuId = $(this).data('menu');
        var menuName = '.' + menuId;
        $(".loading").delay(1000).toggle(0);
        $(menuName).toggleClass("animated bounceInDown");
        $(menuName).toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('close jq-close');
    });

});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/G48bK/

Problem: This uses toggle. The menu is initially hidden with CSS. Toggle sets the menu to"display:none" and then never sets it to "display:block".

Comment: Updated JSFiddle with 2nd function: http://jsfiddle.net/G48bK/1/

Comment: Here is a version that works: [http://jsfiddle.net/d4ajx/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/d4ajx/1/). All I did was replace `$(document)` with `$('body')`

Comment: @medimatrix, Please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @MikeGrabowski I don't quite follow the 2nd Function you have added. Could you explain it? Thanks!

Comment: @big_smile nothing, just removed two first occurences of toggleClass() and toggle() as you probably fire them twice on the same menu causing menu to show and close on every click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on an element, the `click` event is triggered and it bubbles up to all containing elements. Both the body and the document will receive this event.

To fix your code, you need to listen from the same place.

Just change `$(document)` to `$('body')`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d4ajx/1/

See [this diagram](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#dom-event-architecture) for more information.